# Any idea to make this shorter javascript code

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I tried to make this code shorter, but I don't have any idea of this.

First I tried this code

```
else if (language_url === 'html' || 'css' || c# || 'cplusplus) {
-Some Codes-
}
```

But this method cannot be used because, I have to save `language_url` variable each different data.
For example

```
html to html5, css to css3, c# to csharp
```

So I remove this code and write different code, and it works but I want to make it shorter.
It's working but too many `else if` codes looks bad.

Is there any idea to make it shorter?

[Wokring Code]

```
Repo.find({
  'owner.login': userId
}, 'project_type login name language description', function (err, repoData) {
  if (err) console.log(err);

  for (let image of repoData) {
    let language_url = image.language.toLowerCase();
    if (image.language == 'null') {
      image.imageUrl = `/images/app/${image.project_type}.png`;
    } else if (language_url === 'html') {
      language_url = 'html5'
    } else if (language_url === 'css') {
      language_url = 'css3'
    } else if (language_url === 'c#') {
      language_url = 'csharp'
    } else if (language_url === 'c++') {
      language_url = 'cplusplus'
    } else if (image.language !== 'null') {
      console.log(language_url)
    } else {
      // Need Amazon S3 image import code 
    }
    image.imageUrl = `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/konpa/devicon/master/icons/${language_url}/${language_url}-original.svg`;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an object indexed by the input strings, whose values are the output strings:

```
const languages = {
  html: 'html5',
  css: 'css3',
  'c#': 'csharp',
  'c++': 'cplusplus',
}
Repo.find({
  'owner.login': userId
}, 'project_type login name language description', function(err, repoData) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  for (const image of repoData) {
    let language_url = image.language.toLowerCase();
    if (image.language == 'null') {
      image.imageUrl = `/images/app/${image.project_type}.png`;
    } else if (languages[language_url]) {
      language_url = languages[language_url];
    } else {
      // Need Amazon S3 image import code 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe a lookup table approach would make it clean.

```
let lookup = {
 'css' : 'css3',
 'html' : 'html5',
 'c#': 'csharp'
}

let language_url = lookup[image.language.toLowerCase()]
```

The idea here is to replace the bulky `if` conditions to do a lookup on the table, you can also do validation to check the availability of the property using the `lookup.hasOwnProperty` method.